# SSL with no password enconding

Tags: ssl, paypal, https, onlinebanking

I'm new in security matters. I have been ask to work with Unnax Payment API, for make transactions, but when I checked the API, I saw that they send the username and password without any kind of encriptation, just plain text. (https://www.unnax.com/sandbox) - GoTo -tryout- tab.
We wrote them, and they said that  they use SSL and https, so, it's not necesary to encript the information. 
But I have seen other banks which do the same using ssl and https and they DO encryptation. My question is, if is secure enough to send my client 's banks account using the Unnax API?? Thanks

Comment: This question is better asked at security.stackexchange.com and it actually has answers there, like [For an HTTPS web application, is it worthwhile to encrypt the password before POSTing it, to keep a MITM attacker from harversting it?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/66475) and [many others](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Asecurity.stackexchange.com+https+encrypt+password).